# How to fix iMac losing Wi-Fi connection again and again?

Tags: macos, wifi, imac

My iMac loses its Wifi connection from minute to minute. To make it active again, I have to run "*Assist Me...*"  from the Network preferences panel.

This is really, really annoying.

Does anyone know what's going on?

I'm running Mac Os 10.7.4.

Comment: Even if it looses connection you shouldn't have to rerun the Assistant. What happens if you just turn Wi-Fi off and on again in the menu?

Answer (score 6):

You may find that another device is causing interference such as a cordless phone or microwave, or even a neighbour's wifi device. Try changing the channel on your wifi router.

It may be worth using the "alt-trick" to check what's going on with your wifi - when your wifi is connected, mouse over the wifi icon in your system tray, hold down the `alt` key then click on it. You should see some additional info, like the following:

[image]

Keep an eye on the Transmit Rate and RSSI; if they're poor it could be a sign that you need to change the wifi channel.

You can also use [Lion's hidden diagnostic app](http://www.macworld.com/article/1162117/monitor_wi_fi_with_lions_hidden_tool.html) to see what could be causing problems for your wifi.

Answer (score 3):

My router settings were causing the problems for me.

The router was set to 11/**B**/G/N Mixed mode, and as a result I had constant WiFi dropping. I then set the router to 11/G/N and I have not had a single drop.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect fix, just turn off IPv6. That was all my router connection needed!

Comment: Please add more information as to how and why this will help, including references on the internet that back up your assertion.

Answer (score 0):

This happened recently to me (after an OS upgrade to 10.15.6). I also suspect that this is because somehow the OS starts to treat the network differently as before. Anyhow, what worked is just removing the network from the list of known networks and reconnecting.

Answer (score -2):

Change your OS to either 10.6.8 or to 10.8.4

It will help

Comment: You need to add more details on how it works and why.